# Rg.Plugins.Popup is not closing when background is clicked in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have used `rg.plugins.popup` in my application. I have updated the xamarin forms (version="2.5.0.121934"). Now the outer background is clicked it is not closed. I used to close the popup many ways, but not closed, I tried the below code:

> this.CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked = false;

```
protected override bool OnBackgroundClicked()
        {
            Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
            return false;
        }
```

`OnBackgroundClicked` is not calling. How to fix this issue?

Comment: It is an open source project, why not to contact the author on github and ask the question directly? Might be that it is already a known issue check the github.

Comment: I think we'd likely need to see some code to help you pinpoint the problem, please post your `.xaml` file code.

Comment: Hi everybody. I'm author of this library. I have fixed it in the last beta releases. You can test it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand if you know that the correct code is: `this.CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked = true;` (not false), but if this is not working you could try a workaround until this problem is solved.

Basically, add a Grid as the root of your PopupPage and add a Colorless BoxView with a TapGestureRecognizer as a child of the Grid, then just add the actual content as another child of the Grid and set the Tapped of the TapGestureRecognizer to the "BackgroundClicked" code.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yep had same issue had to do stuff as above.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I put all my StackLayout in a ScrollView and I had the same problem. Then I remove the ScrollView and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late answer. But i think someone will need it.
You should override the backbutton from MainActivity.

//add this to inside the Android MainActivity

```
   public async override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed(base.OnBackPressed))
            {
                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                // Do something if there are not any pages in the `PopupStack`
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case it was about not understanding how this plugin works.
First time I used the popup I placed a StackLayout on the center of the screen with `this.CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked = true` and it worked pretty well, the problem was when I placed a GridLayout with columns 10*, 80*, 10* and rows 10*, 80*, 10*. my content was going in grid.rows(1), grid.columns(1). the other lines and columns were just borders. 
If I clicked the borders it would'nt work because I was touching the grid sides and not the actually background.
The solution was change Grid for stacklayout and center it.