# How to close a popup by pressing outside of it

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I used this command CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked = "True" to close the popup but it is not working, how can I close the popup by clicking outside it without having to add a close button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <pages:PopupPage
           xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
                 xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
                 xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="Agtmovel.Views.MnUsuario"
                 CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="True"
                   >
```

Answer (score 2):

Xaml Side Changes= CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="True" => BackgroundClicked="CloseClick"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage
       xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
       xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
       xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       x:Class="Agtmovel.Views.MnUsuario"
       BackgroundClicked="CloseClick">
```

BackgroundClicked Property Event =

```
private async void CloseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
}
```

Comment: if you click on android mobile build in backbutton at button... than your code doesnt work. maybe plugin bug

Answer (score 0):

First maybe try to set this

```
<Popup StaysOpen=”False“>
```

Otherwise I suggest trying something with a lost focus event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set `Fill` or `FillAndExpand` for VerticalOptions and HorizontalOptions of your main view in PopupPage and it will not work as said [here](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/PopupPage#clickable-background-zone).

Although if this not solves your problem, try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996606/6661314) solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/173)  of the plugin.

You can update the version of the plugin or look at the code in [ticket](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/173) to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

just use this on front end

```
....
 xmlns:rg="http://rotorgames.com"
 CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="True">
```